# C# for deployement how to add settings of Library Project to the Main executeable project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am working in Visual Studio 2010 there I have a main project and two other library projects and there reference is added to main project. Every project is having a settings file. After building solution there comes only one .config file for main project but there is no .config file for library projects. Due to this I can not change the settings of those library project externally.

So what will be the solution of this problem that I can have .config files of library projects into my debug/release folder?

app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <section name="Communicator.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        <section name="DatabaseManager.Database.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<applicationSettings>
    <Communicator.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="ApplicationConfigsDirectory" serializeAs="String">
            <value>\Application_Configs</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="MaxMeterConn" serializeAs="String">
            <value>10000</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="MaxPhyConn" serializeAs="String">
            <value>20000</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="ServerIP" serializeAs="String">
            <value>0.0.0.0</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="Port" serializeAs="String">
            <value>1114</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="TCPTimeOut" serializeAs="String">
            <value>3900000000</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="isTCPTimeOut" serializeAs="String">
            <value>True</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="SchedulerPoolingTime" serializeAs="String">
            <value>480000</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="startKAScheduler" serializeAs="String">
            <value>True</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="MinCacheAge" serializeAs="String">
            <value>00:02:00</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="MaxCahceAge" serializeAs="String">
            <value>00:05:00</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="SaveLogToDBFlag" serializeAs="String">
            <value>True</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="Instance" serializeAs="String">
            <value>MDC_Tester</value>
        </setting>
    </Communicator.Properties.Settings>

    <DatabaseManager.Database.Properties.Settings>
      <Setting Name="Server" Type="System.String" Scope="Application">
        <Value Profile="(Default)">192.168.30.181</Value>
      </Setting>
      <Setting Name="Database" Type="System.String" Scope="Application">
        <Value Profile="(Default)">tester</Value>
      </Setting>
      <Setting Name="UserID" Type="System.String" Scope="Application">
        <Value Profile="(Default)">root</Value>
      </Setting>
      <Setting Name="pswd" Type="System.String" Scope="Application">
        <Value Profile="(Default)">nothing</Value>
      </Setting>
      <Setting Name="MaxPoolSize" Type="System.Int32" Scope="Application">
        <Value Profile="(Default)">512</Value>
      </Setting>
    </DatabaseManager.Database.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
<system.runtime.caching>
<memoryCache>
  <namedCaches>
    <add name="default"
         cacheMemoryLimitMegabytes="1024"
         pollingInterval="00:01:30" />
  </namedCaches>
</memoryCache>
</system.runtime.caching>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Having class library depends on configuration have some design smell. the common approach is to parameterize its constructor/method. So anyone can parse Config's value from main executable project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the intended behaviour of settings and config files. You will need to copy the config sections from your library projects into the main project. You will also need to add the corresponding section elements to the applicationSettings section group:

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="SomeLibrary.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="MainProject.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```

then later in the main config:

```
<applicationSettings>
     <SomeLibrary.Properties.Settings>
         <setting name="SomeSetting" serializeAs="String">
            <value>Whatever</value>
         </setting>
     </SomeLibrary.Properties.Settings>
     <MainProject.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="MainSetting" serializeAs="String">
            <value>Yada yada</value>
        </setting>
    </MainProject.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

In the above, the "SomeLibrary" settings type is declared in the main project and settings relating to the library are then set in the main config file alongside the settings for the main project.

Comment: I added the setting to app.config as you explained. but still the values of the parameters are used from the library project settings. And one more thing is that application is not running when I add my solution name before the project name in section group. Like it is working with only "LibraryProject.Properties.Settings" but not with "AwesomeSolution.LibraryProject.Properties.Settings"

Comment: These were just example names so you will need to use your own. I will simplify the example to clarify

Comment: Yes I got your point, I used actual namespaces but that is not working.

Comment: Can you add your `configSettings` `sectionGroup` for your application settings to your question?

Comment: That looks ok. Within the application settings have you included both groups of settings each within their own containing element? Add to your question if poss

Comment: Looks like the values for the database project have been copied from the .settings xml file (because they refer to profiles) whereas they should be copied from the app.config file in the database project

Comment: Thanku So much. This is working I checked after creating new project. but in my exixting project it is not working. There was an issue the default name of Communicator project was also "DatabaseManager.Database" by mistake. I changed this to Communicator. So I think this is not working due to this reason. So I will solve this issue.